# CDK - How to create a SageMaer Model with VPC config

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, aws-cdk

## Question

How to create a SageMaker model with the VPC config with CDK?

CDK SageMaker [CfnModel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_sagemaker/CfnModel.html) has [vpc_config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/host-vpc.html#host-vpc-configure) argument to secure the resource access. This is required not to expose traffic to the internet. The vpc_config argument is specified below which does not tell anything how we can configure it.

```
vpc_config (Union[IResolvable, Forwardref, None]) 
AWS::SageMaker::Model.VpcConfig.
```

The actual class is [VpcConfigProperty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sagemaker.CfnModel.VpcConfigProperty.html) and the code is in aws/cdk/libcdk_elasticsearch.py of the CDK installation.

```
class VpcConfigProperty:
    def __init__(
        self, *, security_group_ids: typing.List[str], subnets: typing.List[str]
    ) -> None:
        """
        :param security_group_ids: ``CfnModel.VpcConfigProperty.SecurityGroupIds``.
        :param subnets: ``CfnModel.VpcConfigProperty.Subnets``.
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the CDK documentation and the Github example is sub-par level. They need to clean up and provide better documentations and examples.

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_ec2,
    aws_sagemaker,
    aws_iam,
    core
)

class HelloCdkStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        sagemaker_execution_role = aws_iam.Role(
            self,
            "SagemakerExecutionRole",
            assumed_by=aws_iam.ServicePrincipal("sagemaker.amazonaws.com")
        )

        sagemaker_vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc(
            self,
            "Vpc",
            cidr="192.168.0.0/16"
        )

        sagemaker_security_group = aws_ec2.SecurityGroup(
            self,
            "SG",
            vpc=sagemaker_vpc
        )

        subnet_selection = sagemaker_vpc.select_subnets(
            subnet_type=aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE
        )

        vpc_config = aws_sagemaker.CfnModel.VpcConfigProperty(
            security_group_ids=[
                sagemaker_security_group.security_group_id
            ],
            # This is how you set the subnets for the SageMaker model
            subnets=subnet_selection.subnet_ids
        )

        sagemaker_model = aws_sagemaker.CfnModel(
            self,
            "SagemakerModel",
            execution_role_arn=sagemaker_execution_role.role_arn,
            containers=[aws_sagemaker.CfnModel.ContainerDefinitionProperty(
                image="123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mymodel:latest"
            )],
            # This is how you setup vpc_config here
            vpc_config=vpc_config
        )
```